# Play partially downloaded video in swift 3

Tags: swift3, alamofire, avplayer, video-processing, video-encoding

I need to play specific part of a video (eg. form 10 sec to 20 sec).
so I use `Alamofire` with custom header range to download just this part of the video:

```
Alamofire.download(videoUrl,
                           method: .get,
                           headers: ["Range":String(format: "bytes=%d-%d", startByte, endByte)],
                           to: destination).response { (response) in

                                completionHandler(response.destinationURL)
        }
```

so far so good, I can see the downloaded file.

But when I'm trying to play it, `avplayer` will fail to do that, I'm using

`videoAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [ObserverContexts.urlAssetDurationKey, ObserverContexts.urlAssetPlayableKey])`

to load that specific keys async but the duration state can not be loaded:

```
let durationStatus = self.videoAsset.statusOfValue(forKey: ObserverContexts.urlAssetDurationKey, error: &durationError)
                guard durationStatus == .loaded else {
                    Logger.log.error("durationStatus not loaded: \(self.videoId)")
                    self.delegate?.onLoadError(error: . durationStatusNotLoaded)
                    return
                }
```

so this error gets triggered and I can't play the video.

I'm not master in video files, but I think the video file has an header and partially downloading will ruin this header and player can not play it.

so any suggestion or idea (even the simplest) would be appreciated.

tnx in advance.

**EDIT:** There is definitely something wrong with video header, if I start download 10 second from start of the video, the video get played for 10 sec, **BUT** the end video time or duration is wrong, how can I fix this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is not the answer to original question, But I managed to achieve my goal by using AVFoundation, now I can download the exact part I want and it is playable :

```
let downloadUrl = URL(string: videoUrl)!
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: downloadUrl)
let composition = AVMutableComposition()
let videoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID:Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
let audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
let tracks = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

guard let assetVideoTrack = tracks.first else {
    Logger.log.debug("video track is not available: \(videoId)")
    completionHandler(nil)
    return
}

let startCM = CMTime(seconds: startSecond, preferredTimescale: 1)
//let endCM = CMTime(seconds: startSecond  + duration, preferredTimescale: 1)
//EDITED
let endCM = CMTime(seconds: duration, preferredTimescale: 1)
let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(startCM, endCM)

do {
    try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: assetVideoTrack, at: CMTimeMake(0, 1))
} catch let errorInsertingVideo {
    Logger.log.debug("can not get video time range: \(videoId) -- \(errorInsertingVideo.localizedDescription)")
    completionHandler(nil)
    return
}

videoTrack.preferredTransform = assetVideoTrack.preferredTransform

guard let assetAudioTrack : AVAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio).first else {
    Logger.log.debug("audio track is not available: \(videoId)")
    completionHandler(nil)
    return
}

do {
    try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: assetAudioTrack, at: CMTimeMake(0, 1))
}catch let errorInsertingAudio {
    Logger.log.debug("can not get audio time range: \(videoId) -- \(errorInsertingAudio.localizedDescription)")
    completionHandler(nil)
    return
}

guard let destinationUrl = self.getDestinationUrl(videoId) else {
    // can not access video cache dir
    Logger.log.error("can not access video cache dir")
    completionHandler(nil)
    return
}

let exportSession : AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)!

exportSession.outputURL = destinationUrl
exportSession.timeRange = timeRange
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie

exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: { 
    switch exportSession.status {
    case .completed:
        let output = exportSession.outputURL!
        completionHandler(output)
    case .failed:
        completionHandler(nil)
        break
    default :
        completionHandler(nil)
        break
    }
})
```

With this trick I can download exactly 10 second (optional) of a video starting from any second at the middle (or start) of the video.

**EDIT**: ok this code can **NOT** download middle part, it only works it you start from begining of the Video.

**EDIT 2**: Fix added.

Comment: The code fixed by changing let endCM = CMTime(seconds: startSecond + duration, preferredTimescale: 1) . Now it can download from the middle.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think IOS or Swift provides this feature of downloading an image from the mid of it and then play it. You can download the video file contents as they are in the form of bits and then can save them with any extension to any file name.
But a video file contains a lots of data in addition to just these bytes that you have downloaded such as header, type, duration, etc. If your downloaded file doesn't contain that data your video will be unplayable.

In this case I think(99% sure) you will have to use **native** code not just Swift to decode the video from a specific time to your desired time.

A lots of free libraries are available, give them a try. One such kind of library is [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/). Check [this](https://github.com/rollmind/ffmpeg-swift-tutorial) as well.

All the best.

Comment: This is not an answer, I  already knew that video file has an info to play correctly and partial download broked it. As you can see I have provided an working alternative so converting video is not an option either, I just want to solve the oq out of curiosity.

Comment: There can't be any other option. I have spent a lot of time some time back on this.

Comment: Nothing is impossible, when there is a question there must be an answer.

Comment: There is an answer but you want very easy answer that will just provide a few lines of code and your video starts playing. But this won't happen. However, all the best.